# Can't use netbook (samsung nc10) touchpad after lubuntu update (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, lubuntu

After the recent update, the touchpad of my netbook samsung nc10 doesn't seem supported anymore, as it doesn't react.

I tried to change some options (TouchpadOff=1) with synclient and gpointing-device-settings but this didn't cause any effects.

Do you have an idea, how I can reactivate the touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

My samsung N145 touchpad had improved a little from updating to 12.04 on lubuntu though I still need to use synclient to get the tap to click to stop going off as it does...

Have you tried installing the samsung support repo? If not it is worth a go.

You can get the repository for extra samsung support

[here](https://launchpad.net/%7Evoria/+archive/ppa)